# Issue with sliding down slopes Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been struggling for a while. When I slide down a slope that has an angle greater than my controller `slopeLimit` which is **45f**, the slide stops a bit too early so that only 90% of the slide is completed. In the photo the slide is "completed" but it's not.

[image]

```cs
// Entire PlayerMovement script
RaycastHit hit;
Vector3 hitPointNormal;
private bool willSlideOnSlopes = true;
public bool isSliding;

void FixedUpdate()
{
    RaycastHit hit;

    if (controller.isGrounded && Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, out hit, 2f))
    {
        hitPointNormal = hit.normal;

        float slopeAngle = Vector3.Angle(hitPointNormal, Vector3.up);
        if (slopeAngle > controller.slopeLimit)
        {
            isSliding = true;
        }
        else
        {
            isSliding = false;
        }
    }
}

void Update()
{
    isGrounded = controller.isGrounded;

    if (isGrounded && velocity.y < 0)
    {
        velocity.y = -2f;
    }

    float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;
    controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);

    velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

    if (isGrounded)
    {
        if (willSlideOnSlopes && isSliding)
        {
            move += new Vector3(hitPointNormal.x, -hitPointNormal.y, hitPointNormal.z) * 2f;
            controller.Move(move * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
    controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

The only way I know to fix it is by duplicating my sliding code and adding a second slide which occurs after the first but it doesn't seem like a good solution.

Comment: would you not simply be sliding until you hit ground?

Comment: I should be yeah since I'm using `Vector3.Angle` along with my `Raycast`, but it stops early. My script is as simplified as possible so there's no issue that stands out.

Comment: Well by ray casting 1 unit down and stopping sliding depending on that id say that doesnt help

Comment: I believe that the Raycast is hitting the ground so it's no longer detecting an angle, and then stops sliding. Using a SphereCast solves this issue but causes many more, so I'm not sure what options are left.

Comment: why use a raycase to detect the floor, why not let it slide until it physically hits the floor - your raycast will see the floor 2m away!!

Comment: @BugFinder Yeah you're right, I've been trying to do that for the last few hours but for some reason my player will not slide without that Raycast. Are you talking about getting rid of the Vector3.Angle and the Raycast too?